# Querying for Entities with no parents

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm working on converting an application from db to ndb, and am working on making my queries more efficient. The application has become a bit slow with the increase in amount of data, causing us to realize that the queries are pretty inefficient.

**Background:**

Our stripped-down data model is similar to this (feel free to criticize):

```
class ServiceRequest(ndb.Model):
  technician = ndb.UserProperty()
  application = ndb.KeyProperty()  # ServiceRequestApplication kind


class ServiceRequestApplication(ndb.Model):
  applicant = ndb.UserProperty()
```

Admins can "approve" a ServiceRequestApplication for a ServiceRequest. ServiceRequestApplications are instantiated with a parent ServiceRequest. If a ServiceRequestApplication is approved, the application's key is stored in the request's application property.

The tricky part:

There can be multiple ServiceRequest entities for 1 actual service appointment (1 per technician). We have one ServiceRequest, and if there are multiple techs needed, we create additional ServiceRequests, with the main ServiceRequest as a parent. We originally approached the problem this way because ancestor queries would be pretty easy, including some other reasons with regards to the way this data was going to be queried/represented.

Can anyone think of a way to query for ServiceRequest entities that *don't* have children ServiceRequests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the subject you ask about querying for entities with no parents; in the body you ask about querying for entities with no children. In either case, though, the answer is the same: This isn't possible with standard App Engine indexes. The former requires searching for something that is *not* present in the key (which isn't possible the way indexes are structured), and the latter requires a join, since it's selecting entities based on properties (or presence) of other entities.

Instead, you will need to denormalize: add a property to ServiceRequest that indicates if it's a root entity, or if it has children, as appropriate.